# Cannot open Network-Manager-Gnome LMDE

Tags: linux, networking, debian, gnome, linux-mint

Hi I am using the Linux Mint Debian Version

After installing the recent Update pack 7, I cannot open The Networkmanager-gnome window.
The icon on the Dock appears and I can switch on/off any networks how ever When I click on the network connections button the window "tries" to load but closes instantly
I have tried removing and reinstalling network manager. So far, nothing has worked.

I am using Gnome shell 3.4

Comment: Can you access it normally if you go through Gnome's control center => network?

Comment: Nope Its the same.